# How to run code script from tkinter script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I try to use tkinter to run the test.py script. In tkinter GUI, I had 4 button , but currently only 2 button I want to use for test.py :

Connecting button  which open the test.py file
Home cablibrate which run the print "Hi" in test.py

What I want:

So when user press connecting button , the test.py will open and print "welcome" on the terminal  ( test.py running parallel with the tkinter GUI ). After that , if the button home cablibrate is pressing ,  the tkinter GUI will pass the value n equal 2 to the test.py and run the condition n>2 in test.py to print "hi"

Issue:

1/ I try to use subprocess in tkinter to open and print "welcome" on test.py, but nothing print out , it only add different value into my test.py.I think i use the wrong function. However , I not sure how to fix this ?

2/ Since there is a error when open test.py and print . I havent write the pass parameter condition for home cablibrate function. I also not sure how to pass communicate between two script. Could you guy give me some advice on this ?

tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
 

class graphic(tk.Tk,Popen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reset_clock = 0
        self.check_value = 0 
        self.done = 0
        self.minute = 1 
        self.second = 0   
        self.title('Automation Cleaning Process')
        self.geometry('1100x800+100+100')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index")
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...")
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu)
        self.integer_variable_x_value = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer_variable_y_value = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer_variable_z_value = tk.IntVar() 
        self.integer_variable_r_value = tk.IntVar() 
        self.integer_variable_x_value.set(0)
        self.integer_variable_y_value.set(0)
        self.integer_variable_z_value.set(0)
        self.integer_variable_r_value.set(0) 
        
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self) 
        self.tab_1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab_2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab_2,text = 'HOME')
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab_1,text = 'Option')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
        
        self.set_button()
        self.set_text_gui()
        self.set_timer_counter_process(self.minute,self.second)
        self.update_output(200,300,400,500)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def set_button(self):
        self.button_1 = ttk.Button (self.tab_1,text = "Home Cabliration", command = self.button_1_clicked,  width = 50) 
        self.button_1.place(x=380,y=200)
        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.tab_1, text='Automation Process',command=self.button_2_clicked_clock_counting_down, width = 50)
        self.button_2.place(x=380,y=300)
        self.button_3 = ttk.Button(self.tab_1, text='Stop',command=self.button_3_clicked, width = 50)
        self.button_3.place(x=380,y=400)
        self.button_connected = ttk.Button (self.tab_2,text = "Connecting Dobot" , command=self.button_connected_clicked, width=50)
        self.button_connected.place(x=400,y=300)
        
    

    def button_connected_clicked(self): 
        self.connecting = tk.Label(self.tab_2,text = "Connecting ...", font=("Inter", 25))
        self.connecting.place(x = 450  , y = 350)
        self.dobot_COM_port()
            

    def dobot_COM_port(self): 
        self.source ='C:/Users/ching/OneDrive/Desktop/DobotGUI/test.py'
        self.file_run  = open(self.source,'w+')
        self.process_run_parallel = Popen(["ls","-all"], universal_newlines=True, stdout=self.file_run, stderr=PIPE)
        
        

    def button_1_clicked(self): 
     self.button_1_value = 1
     print (self.button_1_value)
     print ("button 1 click ")
   
    def button_2_clicked_clock_counting_down(self):
     self.done = 1 
     self.button_2_value = 2
     print (self.button_2_value)
     print ("button 2 click ")

    def button_3_clicked(self): 
     self.button_3_value = 3
     print (self.button_3_value)
     print ("button 3 click ")

 
    def set_text_gui(self): 
        #declare label 
        self.x_axis = tk.Label(self.tab_2,text = "x value:", font=("Inter", 25))
        self.y_axis = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "y value:", font=("Inter",25))
        self.z_axis = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "z value:", font=("Inter",25))
        self.r_axis = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "r value:", font=("Inter",25))
    
    
        self.x_axis_value = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "x value:", font=("Inter",25))
        self.y_axis_value= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "y value:", font=("Inter", 25))
        self.z_axis_value = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "z value:", font=("Inter",25))
        self.r_axis_value= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "r value:", font=("Inter", 25))

        self.time_title = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "Time Process:", font=("Inter",30))
        self.time_colon= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = ":", font=("Inter",  30))
        self.min_label= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "min", font=("Inter", 30))
        self.second_label=tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "sec", font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_minute = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_second = tk.Label (self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_minute_zero_add = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_second_zero_add = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        # position label 
        
        self.x_axis.place(x = 85  , y = 150)
        self.y_axis.place(x = 330 , y = 150)
        self.z_axis.place(x = 575 , y = 150)
        self.r_axis.place(x = 820 , y = 150)

        self.x_axis_value.place(x = 200 , y = 150)
        self.y_axis_value.place(x = 445 , y = 150)
        self.z_axis_value.place(x = 695 , y = 150)
        self.r_axis_value.place(x = 935 , y = 150)

        self.time_title.place(x=85,y=590) 
        self.time_colon.place(x =230,y=650)
        self.min_label.place(x=150,y=650)
        self.second_label.place(x=335,y=650)
        self.label_minute.place(x = 120 , y = 650)
        self.label_second.place(x=  278 , y = 650)
        self.label_minute_zero_add.place(x=  90 ,y=650)
        self.label_second_zero_add.place(x = 250 ,y= 650)

    def update_output(self , input_dobot_x, input_dobot_y, input_dobot_z , input_dobot_r):
        # update x-axis 
        self.integer_variable_x_value.set(input_dobot_x)
        self.x_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_x_value.get()))
        # update y axis 
        self.integer_variable_y_value.set(input_dobot_y)
        self.y_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_y_value.get()))
        # update z axis 
        self.integer_variable_z_value.set(input_dobot_z)
        self.z_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_z_value.get()))
        
        # update r axis
        self.integer_variable_r_value.set(input_dobot_r)
        self.r_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_r_value.get()))
        
        #update all the variable every 100secs to GUI 
        self.after(100,self.update)

    def set_timer_counter_process(self,minute,second):
        print(self.done)  
        self.label_minute['text'] = minute
        self.label_second['text'] = second
        check_minute_length = len(str(minute))
        check_second_length = len(str(second))
        if check_minute_length == 1: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] = 0 
        else: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] =''

        if check_second_length == 1:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] = 0  
        else:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] ='' 

        if self.done == 1:      
            if second  > 0 :
                second = second - 1       
            elif second <= 0 :
                if minute > 0:
                    minute  = minute - 1  
                    second  = 60 
                else:
                    self.done = 0
        else:
            minute = 1
            second = 0           
        self.after(1000, self.set_timer_counter_process, minute , second) 



        

User_graphic = graphic()
User_graphic.mainloop()
```

test.py:

```
  

n = 0 ; 
print("welcome")

if (n > 1): 
    print ("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s two things you can do here. Let me explain first, you do not need subprocess to solve this problem, there is built in python “stuff” to accomplish this. If you want to be syntactically correct and asynchronous, in test.py you can write this:

```
async def main():
    n=0
    print(“welcome”)

    if n > 1:
        print(“hi”)
```

Then in your main tkinter file you can put this at the top of your script:

```
import main from test
```

Then when you want to call/run test, you can do this:

```
main()
```

You can also use import lib or directly importing it in the function but that is not recommended

Comment: This should raise an exception, you can't just call `async` functions, it's not how it works., also fix your quotes.

Comment: @Chi if you're not sure you probably shouldn't use it. Most certainly don't use it to just run python files. It's meant for essentially when you want to call command line commands from Python for different processes and executables but usually not Python and certainly it's not the solution in this case.

Comment: Importing could work for this simple case . However, in the future , I want to add the serial connection into the test.py to connect the laptop with robot which use python api to run. Hence I want to run the test.py parallel with the tkinter instead of importing method .

Comment: @Chi no, you still want to import it, define key functions and classes in that file, import that stuff and run it in a different process or, perhaps, a thread might be a better/easier choice if it's a bunch of I/O. Do it from the main file.

Comment: @ Matiss , Thank for the advice. I think my direction is wrong. What library I should use to run the test.py parallel with the tikinter GUI?

Comment: Ah yes I was thinking in my js mind that I could just run async functions like that, my bad

Comment: @Chi I’m pretty sure asyncio has a create background task, might wanna check that out

Comment: @Zachary I will check it out